# ASP.NET MVC - Xml Export - formatting the file name according to class attributes

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, export

I have this class, which takes the selected file in the grid

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportXml(string apontamentos)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] arrApontamentos = apontamentos.Split(';');
            var listApontamentoId = arrApontamentos.Select(x => new Guid(x)).ToList();
            var apontamentosViewModel = this._apontamentoAppService.ObterTodos(listApontamentoId);

            List<ApontamentoExportarViewModel> listXml = new List<ApontamentoExportarViewModel>();

            int item = 1;
            foreach (var informacaoApontamentoVM in apontamentosViewModel)
            {

                listXml.Add(new ApontamentoExportarViewModel
                {
                    Item = item,
                    Equipamento = informacaoApontamentoVM.Barco.SapId,
                    Atendimento = informacaoApontamentoVM.Atendimento,
                    Escala = informacaoApontamentoVM.LocalDaOperacao.Abreviacao,
                    DescricaoDaOperacao = informacaoApontamentoVM.CodigosDeOperacao.Descricao,
                    //GrupoDeCodigo = "xxx",
                    CodigoOperacao = informacaoApontamentoVM.CodigosDeOperacao.Codigo,
                    DataInicial = string.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", informacaoApontamentoVM.DataInicio),
                    HoraInicial = string.Format("{0:HH.mm.ss}", informacaoApontamentoVM.DataInicio),
                    DataFinal = string.Format("{0:dd:MM:yyyy}", informacaoApontamentoVM.DataTermino),
                    HoraFinal = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", informacaoApontamentoVM.DataTermino),
                    Observacoes = informacaoApontamentoVM.Observacao
                });
                item++;
            }
            var status = this._apontamentoAppService.ObterDescricaoStatusApontamento(Domain.Apontamentos.StatusApontamento.Exportado);
            this._apontamentoAppService.AtualizarStatus(apontamentosViewModel.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(), status);
            return new XmlActionResult<ApontamentoExportarViewModel>(listXml);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

And a i have that other one, which does export and xml format and filename

```
  public class XmlActionResult<T> : ActionResult
  {
    public XmlActionResult(List<T> data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public List<T> Data { get; private set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

        // TODO: Use your preferred xml serializer 
        // to serialize the model to the response stream :
        // context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream
        ApontamentoExportarViewModel apontamentoExportarViewModel = new ApontamentoExportarViewModel();
        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            // for example foo.bak
            FileName = string.Format("MA_"+ "Equipamento" + "_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss}.xml", DateTime.Now),


            // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
            // the browser to try to show the file inline
            Inline = false,
        };
        var root = new XmlRootAttribute("meadinkent");
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(Data.GetType(), root);
        context.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        x.Serialize(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, Data);


    }
}
```

}

Basically, I need to get the "Equipamento" attribute and insert it into the file name.

The information from the "ApontamentoExportarViewModel" class is coming from the "Data" attribute, but how do you find the information inside that list? Remembering that I only need the information of the attribute "Equipment"

How would I bring the value of this attribute to the XmlActionResult class?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've got it in `Data` in the XmlActionResult, but because it's a `List<T>`, it could be anything. In this case, it's your `ApontamentoExportarViewModel` view model.

Should this XmlActionResult method be able to work with various kinds of objects, or only with `ApontamentoExportarViewModel`? If with various types, then not every one of those types will have a `Equipamento` property. In that case, you would have to do something like:

```
var fileName = "default";
if(Data is List<ApontamentoExportarViewModel>)
{
    var record = (Data as List<ApontamentoExportarViewModel>).FirstOrDefault(); // what should happen if there's more than one?
    if (record != null)
        fileName = record.Equipamento;
}
```

and then later:

```
FileName = string.Format("MA_"+ fileName + "_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss}.xml", DateTime.Now);
```

Or something like that.

If you are sure that every object that comes in to your method will have a `Equipamento` property, then you could create a base class from which you derive your view model classes that has `Equipamento`, or an interface, and then alter your method to not accept any type (`<T>`), but rather only classes that derive from the base class / implement the interface.